# (BUKKIT) The method getTargetBlock isn't working

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I think (hope) I'm using the correct arguments. `player.getTargetBlock` is needed for lots of things in bukkit, but it never works for me! The only time it works is with a lightning bolt spawner.

Here is the bit that doesn't work:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractBlockTeleport(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BONE) {
        player.getWorld().teleport(player.getTargetBlock(null, 200));
        player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERMAN_TELEPORT, 10, 1);
    }
}
```

Anyone help?

Comment: What kind of problem are you experiencing? Is nothing happening or is an error being thrown? Did you register the listener etc.?

Comment: Please try more effort on your own before asking a question. For example, test if your listener works at all. If no, ask a question about how to set up a listener. If something else doesn't work, ask a question about only that.

Comment: Please don't materially alter your existing questions. You've received an answer for the original version, you cannot then reuse the post to ask a different question.

Answer (score 4):

There are three reasons as to why your code most likely won't work:

1. You're attempting to teleport the player's "world" (`player.getWorld().teleport`) and not the player itself. As far as I can tell from the Bukkit 1.8.3 API, there is no `teleport()` method for worlds. I'm assuming you are trying to teleport the player in which case `player.teleport(location/entity)` will work.
2. The teleport() method takes a location or entity as an argument, not a block. You'll need to pass it the location of the target block with `block.getLocation()`.
3. Depending on which version of Bukkit you are using and whether you are also using Craftbukkit, you should probably cast the first argument of the getTargetBlock() method to a Set in order to avoid ambiguity (there is another method (deprecated) which takes a HashSet as the first argument).

In your event method, I would also teleport the player to a location above the block so as not to teleport the player inside the block. Last but not least, make sure that your event listener class has been registered. Below is some example code that I tested:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractBlockTeleport(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    //Null check isn't necessary anymore, an empty item will have Material.AIR and getTargetBlock() now also works if no target block is found
    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.BONE) {
        Location playerLoc = player.getLocation(); //Get the player's location
        Location target = player.getTargetBlock((Set) null, 200).getLocation().clone().add(0, 1, 0); //Get the block location + 1 y
        target.setYaw(playerLoc.getYaw()); //Set the yaw of the target location to the player's yaw
        target.setPitch(playerLoc.getPitch()); //Set the pitch of the target location to the player's pitch
        player.teleport(target); //Teleport player
        player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERMAN_TELEPORT, 10, 1); //Play sound
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, why the downvote? I tried this code and it worked and it seems to answer Sporech's question as to why his method isn't working. Any constructive feedback or advice as to how I could improve the answer?

Comment: Sorry, for the unclearness of the actual error. The actual error i'm getting is an ambiguity error. It doesn't like the parameters and in the getTargetBlock bit, it has a line through it :/

Comment: :D your code worked! i had tried removing the player.getWorld, but same thing happened. It must have been the clone bit. can you clarify what it exactly does so i know for future?

Comment: Glad it worked! The clone bit simply gives you an exact duplicate of the object, allowing you to edit a new copy instead of changing the original reference (the = or "assignment" operator only duplicates the reference to the object). It probably doesn't matter much in this example, although sometimes it's necessary to avoid editing the original location. The casting of the first argument (removing the ambiguity) and getLocation() method for the block probably did the trick. I would highly appreciate it if you would accept/upvote my answer since it helped :)

Comment: I'm getting a new problem. It always makes me face north (positive Z) whenever i teleport. how to i manipulate the direction the player is looking?

Comment: A Location in Bukkit contains a world, x, y and z coordinates as well as a yaw and pitch (these determine the rotation around the horizontal and vertical axis). A block location will always have a yaw and pitch of 0, which is why the player is always facing the same way. You can change the yaw and pitch of a location using setYaw() and setPitch(). I updated the example code above to teleport the player to the location facing the same direction as he was before teleporting.

Comment: I tries copying the modded code, but it still makes me face the same direction :(. ill modify my question to show the code:

Comment: I tried my own code as well as your version again, and both worked perfectly fine. Are you sure your plugin jar contains the updated code? One small edit I would make: You can shorten the last three lines that decrease the player's hunger level to `player.setFoodLevel(player.getFoodLevel() - 6);`

Comment: It worked this time! i didn't modify the code or anything. Must have forgotten to upload it or something stupid. Thank you for all your support!